# Multiple Domains in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain

I want to create a multilanguage Website based on WordPress.

I have 2 domains: `domain.com` and `domain.de`.

How is it possible to redirect the `domain.de` to `de.domain.com` and `domain.com` to `en.domain.com`.

I don't have a V-Server, it's just a Webserver.

At the moment I'm using this plugin for my multilingual WordPress: http://dev.xiligroup.com/?cat=393&lang=en_us

Comment: try the WordPress stack exchange site

Answer (score 0):

1. Use mod_rewrite http://www.phatz.com/301redirect.php
2. You could put in your domain.de - site file index.php with following code

   header('Location: http://de.domain.com')

and in domain.com put file with

```
header('Location: http://en.domain.com')
```